# RESTful API POST call request without a body

Tags: rest, api, post, api-design

I want to create a new call in my API that links two already created resources together. Therefore, I don't need to pass any json entities in the post body I just need the resources IDs which I am passing in the URL. Is that a wrong practice? so basically my request now is only a simple path {cid}/projects/{projectID}/subcontractors/{subcontractorID}
and in the post call method I extract the resources IDs from the path and I link them. The response is only either pass or fail {"success":true}. Is that a wrong practice? Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How you will design your API is really up to you. From a technical point of view, a `POST` request with an empty payload is completely fine.

---

However, assuming that you intend to add a *contractor* to a *project*, I think it could be better expressed with a payload:

```
POST /projects/1/contractors HTTP/1.1
Host: api.example.org
Content-Type: application/json

{ "contractorId": 100 }
```

This approach is specially useful if you need to manage more information for that *contractor* in that *project*. If above request succeeds, the response would contain the `201` status code along with a `Location` header that identifies the newly created resource.

Comment: but I already have another post call for creating the contractor similar to your example but with few extra fields:
POST /projects/1/contractors
Host: api.example.org
Content-Type: application/json

{ 
  "ContarctorName":"Contractor 1",
"ContarctorAddress":"Address 123",
}
So the new linking POST call has to be different.

Comment: @ZuzuJH I would use `POST /contractors` to create contractors and `POST /projects/{id}/contractors` to linking the contractors to a project.

Comment: I do apologies for not explaining my issue fully. so our system has two level company level and project level. therefore we have a call for adding & linking the subcontractor at the company level and we have a call for  for adding & linking the subcontractor at the project level. The call that I am trying to achieve now is just for linking the contractors that are already existing at the company level to the project level. I hope that makes sense now.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are linking the already existing resources - projects and contractors. I wouldn't prefer the POST method.
Instead I would use the [PATCH](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789)  method (as I am only editing the partial content of the existing resources)
Either the payload or the request URL methods are acceptable.

Request URL:

```
PATCH /projects/3/contractors/23 HTTP/1.1
HOST example.com/api
```

Payload

```
PATCH /projects/3/contractors HTTP/1.1
HOST example.com/api
Content-Type: application/json
{ "contractor_id": 23 }
```

A successful response is indicated by `200` status code which may contain the payload, or
`204` response

Comment: Thank you so much. I never knew about this http method